# Y-Axis minimum value not dynamic in Jqplot Zoom Line - chart

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I am using `Jqplot` for `Line chart with zoom enabled`, the problem I am facing is that some of the points whose ordinate is less than majority of the points are not shown on graph. I have attached an image of the graph I am getting.

![Graph]
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8mWw.jpg

As it can be seen that there are points of value less than `10000`, but those points are not visible.So I want these points to appear normally on the graph, any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can u simulate the same on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @dreamweiver I have updated the link of the graph snapshot, please let me know if that makes my question clear enough.

Comment: I understood your problem,just wanted the complete environment setup on a editor such as jsfiddle so  that any of us from SO can  try solve. if your new to jsfiddle, then go to http://jsfiddle.net and add the code to respective section.

Comment: @dreamweiver I tried to stimulate it on http://jsfiddle.net but somehow it doesn't work. I had a hard time solving the issue, here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/nC5t6/8/, I would really appreciate any help as I am frustrated by this silly error that I would have been making.

Comment: Check if this is of any use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732335/get-list-of-data-points-in-the-canvas-after-zoom-jqplot