# Interval Selection Event in Primefaces Chart

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, jqplot, linechart

I have a dynamic LineChart. I am setting the zoom to `false` but I want to be able to trigger an Ajax Event when selecting an area in the Chart (like the zoom functionnality when selecting the area you want to zoom), I want to call a server method and getting the max and min x axis values of the selected area.
Can anyone help with this?

Else if I set the zoom to `true`, is there any way to get the values from the zoomed area ?

Comment: Search for dupl!cates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732335/get-list-of-data-points-in-the-canvas-after-zoom-jqplot#

Comment: It is not a duplicate, the question you posted he is generating the jqPlot chart manually in javascript, but in my case it's generated dynamically in my java bean.

Comment: Ok this is my source code for the chart, can you tell me how to use the answer posted in that question in my case?
`<p:chart id="myPlot" type="line" model="#{actionsBean.prevSnapshotModel}"
 responsive="true"
 widgetVar="myLineChartWV"  />`

Comment: He/She binds a function to the zoom event and receives the data in there. So it does not automatically mean way the data is 'generated' matters. Or in other words: take a look at the generated html source of your chart. Lots of javascript in there WITH the points

Comment: JSF (and PrimeFaces) is in this context nothing more than an html/css/javascript generator.

Comment: Ok I am understanding, so in my case how can I get the jqPlot chart object because I tried a couple of source codes but it's not working?

Comment: What DID you try? Dit you use your browser developer tool to see what `PF('myLineChartWV")` shows? There is a plot on there... which, maybe not surprisingly contains a target, axis etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PrimeFaces and JSF is in this context nothing more than an html/javascript/css generator. If you look at the source of the generated page in your browser developer tool, you'll see a lot of javascript, including all datapoints.

```
<script id="j_idt87_s" type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){PrimeFaces.cw('Chart','chart'{
        id:'j_idt87',
        type:'line',
        data:[[[1,2],[2,1],[3,3],[4,6],[5,8]],[[1,6],[2,3],[3,2],[4,7],[5,9]]],
        title:"Zoom",
        legendPosition:"e",
        axes:{
            xaxis:{
              label:"",
              renderer:$.jqplot.LinearAxisRenderer,
              tickOptions:{angle:0}},
            yaxis: {
              label:"",
              min:0,
              max:10,
              renderer:$.jqplot.LinearAxisRenderer,
              tickOptions:{angle:0}}
         },
         series:[{label:'Series 1',renderer: $.jqplot.LineRenderer,showLine:true,markerOptions:{show:true, style:'filledCircle'}},{label:'Series 2',renderer: $.jqplot.LineRenderer,showLine:true,markerOptions:{show:true, style:'filledCircle'}}],zoom:true,datatip:true},'charts');});
    </script>
```

So the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732335/get-list-of-data-points-in-the-canvas-after-zoom-jqplot#) question is valid for the PrimeFaces charts as well.

Running the following code (from the link above) in your browser developer tool on the [zoom examples](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/zoom.xhtml) will show you the data points that fall in your zoom region

```
chart = PF('chart').plot;
PF('chart').plot.target.bind('jqplotZoom', function(ev, gridpos, datapos, plot, cursor){
    var plotData =  plot.series[0].data;
    for (var i=0; i< plotData.length; i++) {
        if(plotData[i][0] >= chart.axes.xaxis.min && plotData[i][0] <= chart.axes.xaxis.max ) {
            //this dataset from the original is within the zoomed region
            //You can save these datapoints in a new array
            //This new array will contain your zoom dataset
            //for ex: zoomDataset.push(plotData[i]);
            console.log(plotData[i]);
        }
    }
});
```

Replacing `PF(çhart')` with `PF('myLineChartWV')` will make it work for your example to

Once you have gathered the data, you can use this in e.g. a PrimeFaces `remoteCommand` to pass it to the server.

Notice that this **only takes the x-axis** value of the zoom into account. If you want the y-axis taken into account to (so the real zoom area), add

```
  plotData[i][1] >= chart.axes.yaxis.min && plotData[i][1] <= chart.axes.yaxis.max
```

to the if-statement in the loop.

Also notice it just **takes the first series**. If you have multiple, you have some simple homework to do.

Comment: I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'plot' of undefined` in my console.

Comment: Then you either do something wrong (what does `PF('myLineChartWV')` show you on your console (dig into things by clicking them)) or you have an old PF version which does not support this

Comment: I am using PF 5.2 and `PF('myLineChartWV')` is printing undefined

Comment: then myLineChartWV is not your widgetVar

Comment: Ok I am figuring out why it's printing undefined now, because the panel that contains the chart is generated in a row of a datatable and it's rendered when user expand the row. I will try to print the widgetVar value when expanding the row

Comment: Ok I binded a function to the row expand action and it's printing for `PF('myLineChartWV')`  in the console  `[object Object]`

Comment: ok, so now you can go forward... Good luck (and don't forget to accept the answer and upvote)

Comment: Ok I am trying to make it work now but according to your help and answers I am assuming that your answer is correct. Thanks :)

Comment: You can copy-paste the javascript code above in the your browser developer tool if you have the PrimeFaces showcase open on the chart zoom page and see it work!

Comment: plotdata[i] **IS** the value (x,y in an array) that falls in the zoomed area

Comment: It's working now, thank you very much you saved my life :)